# Oracle forms FRM-40102:RECORD MUST BE ENTERED OR DELETED FIRST

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I made this in a button on oracle forms to fill a form automatically from several table records and when I run the form it throws the error FRM - 40102 RECORD MUST BE ENTERED OR DELETED FIRST

I tried manually deleting the default record first but it doesn't seem to change.

```
DECLARE
 /* cursor declaration */

 CURSOR C IS 
 SELECT ALU.IDEALU, EVA.IDEEVA, UNI.IDEUNI, MAT.IDEMAT
 FROM ALU, EVA, UNI, MAT
 ORDER BY ALU.IDEALU;

 ALT NUMBER;
 R C%ROWTYPE;
 N NUMBER;
 errnum NUMBER       := ERROR_CODE; 
   V_CONT NUMBER;
   AL_CONT NUMBER;
 V_ADD_AMT NUMBER; 
 V_ADD_DEDUCT NUMBER; 
 V_SAL_ADD_AMT NUMBER;
 BEGIN

 SELECT COUNT(IDEALU) INTO AL_CONT
 FROM ALU;

/*cursor open*/
 OPEN C;
 --================= 
   IF errnum = 40508 THEN     
        ALT:=SHOW_ALERT('FAIL');
        RAISE Form_Trigger_Failure; 
   END IF;      
 --================     
      GO_BLOCK('CAAE');     
      IF AL_CONT=0 THEN
      FIRST_RECORD;
      ALT:=SHOW_ALERT('FAIL');
      ELSE
           LAST_RECORD;
           NEXT_RECORD;
      END IF;
      NEXT_RECORD;
 LOOP
  FETCH C INTO R;               ----cursor fetch/read      
  :CAAE.CAAEALU:=R.IDEALU;         --- data assign...
  :CAAE.CAAEEVA:=R.IDEEVA;
  :CAAE.CAAEUNI:=R.IDEUNI;
  :CAAE.CAAEMAT:=R.IDEMAT;
  EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND; 
  NEXT_RECORD;  
 END LOOP;
 PREVIOUS_RECORD;
 CLOSE C;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you do 2 times a next_record without filling any fields:

```
 IF AL_CONT=0 THEN
      FIRST_RECORD;
      ALT:=SHOW_ALERT('FAIL');
      ELSE
           LAST_RECORD;
           NEXT_RECORD;
      END IF;
      NEXT_RECORD;
```

The next_record after the if statement is not needed.
Now you try to go from an empty record to a next record and then the system gives you the error message you need to fill it first

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your Next_Record; command, what you can do is check for the below condition for every next_record below is the example:

```
IF :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE' AND :CAAE.CAAEALU IS NOT NULL THEN
   NEXT_RECORD;
END IF;
```

Try this it will work, or comment then if still any issue occurs.